# Can i play mp3 file from url in Flash using actionscript

Tags: flash, url, actionscript, mp3, playback

I have made a player that is being embedded in my application but when i wan to play a mp3 file by providing its Url it does not able to play on HTML whereas same url is played when i run direct swf file of player.

for example: it is playing file placed on my Server but can't play a file having url like 
http://www.xyx.com/akdfjak f/akdjk/RemoteFile.mp3

but the same file is played when SWF is opened
 so want to play it on player embedded in my HTML.

Comment: I think you'll need to rephrase your question as it is not clear enough what the problem is you have. Can you post any code you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download your mp3 using URLLoader object. If you want realtime sound playing, you need a mediaserver, as far as I know.

Comment: so that means Live Streaming is not possible it this case??

Comment: As far as I know, you can't make live streaming without streaming server.

Comment: Thanks for spending time for my query !